# Dynamic button Ids - Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, button, dynamic

I have a number of buttons generated from a for loop as follows and the id = like:

```
<button type="submit" id = "like" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm like"><span id="tx-like">Like</span></button>
```

I have a script that changes the "like" to "unlike" and "unlike" to "like", it gets element by Id:

```
$( function() {
        $('#like').click( function() {
            var t = $("#tx-like").html();
            if(t == 'Like'){
                $("#tx-like").html("Unlike");
            }else{
                $("#tx-like").html("Like");
            }
        } );
    } );
```

This is only functional on the first button since it taking the id. How I can get it functional on all buttons that are generated dynamically?

Comment: id's are unique. you can not share an id between elements.

Comment: Is there a way those ids to be incremental with a number like: button 1 id is like1, button2 id is like2, and so on. Then, the JavaScript function can take those ids and do the job?

Comment: of course there is. add your number to the id. But I suggest using class' instead.

Comment: I used a class. it is unliking/liking everything at once. it's not efficient. How it can be done with dynamic ids?

Comment: select all with your custom class and use that select list perform your actions against.

Comment: @StevenStark the class is changing all buttons at once. I made the ids look like this: like1, like2, like3 ..., but how I can do my function above to work with those dynamic ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments above, you should not have multiple IDs in the same page.
You could use classes instead, but even if it would work, there is a better approach which is to use `data-attributes`.

```js
// Retrieves all your elements using the `data-like` attribute.
const likes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-like]');

// For each element as `el`
likes.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // Get its `data-like` value.
    const { like } = el.dataset;

    // If the value is 'false':
    if (like === 'false') {
      el.innerText = 'Dislike';
      el.dataset.like = 'true';
      return;
    }

    // Else...
    el.innerText = 'Like';
    el.dataset.like = 'false';
  });
});
```

```css
/* You can easily customize your elements according to their current state. */

.like[data-like="true"] {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.like[data-like="false"] {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Remove duplicate IDs and use `data-like` instead. -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm like" data-like="false">Like</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm like" data-like="false">Like</button>
```

Comment: Didnt work. I know the snippet did and this exactly what I want. Is there any libraries I need to include?

Comment: I don't. I tried to use in my application, it didn't work. I tried a test separately as the snippet but didnt do the function. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't really help without seeing the application. Try to find the problem step by step: is your javascript loaded ? Then, does the `likes` constante returns results? Then, is the click event triggered? etc.

Comment: I tried it on jsfiddle and it worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Once I remove it, it works but I want it to work with ajax. Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your post and add your Ajax code, or create a new post.